# CSS: Flex element has additional space when it contains an input

Tags: html, css

Why does the `.content` element have some extra space when I set the `.input-field` to have a `width` of `20%` and `input` to have a `width` of `100%`? and when I remove the `width: 20%` on the `.content`. the input takes up the extra space and doesn't have that issue anymore. (I wanted to restrict the width of input so I added the `width:20%` on the `.input-field`.

[image: Issue]

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content:nth-child(1) {
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
.input-field {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 10rem;
  max-width: 20rem;
}
label {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="input-field">
      <label>hey</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"><p>hey</p></div>
  <div class="content"><p>you</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percentages are relative to the parent element. When you give `20%` to the `.input-field` it would be relative to the parent .ie., the `.content` so it is occupying 20% of `.content` but it is lower than the min width so it is falling back to `min-width: 10rem` and leaving  an empty space at the end since even `10rem` is less than 100% of `.content`. If you don't want the extra space you can:

- Set `width:min-content` to `.content` so it does just occupies then intrinsic minimum width of the content which is kind of awkward.
- Set `width:100%` to `.input-field` and control the size of its parent `.content`.

```html
<style>
  .content {
    width: min-content;
  }
  *{
      margin:0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .parent {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
  }
  .content:nth-child(1) {
      display: flex;
      align-self: flex-end;
  }
  input {
      width: 100%;
  }
  .input-field {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      width: 20%;
      min-width: 10rem;
      max-width: 20rem;
  }
  label {
      margin-right: 0.5rem;
  }
</style>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">
      <div class="input-field">
          <label>hey</label>
          <input type="text">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"><p>hey</p></div>
  <div class="content"><p>you</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would it occupy a precentage of the `.content` tho? Would you mind explaining it? Thanks.

Comment: @j.xiang Updated the answer with more explanation. You can check https://jameshfisher.com/2019/12/29/what-are-css-percentages/ for clearer explanation

Comment: Yup its clear for me. Just one more thing, I didn't explicitly set the width of the `.content` so how did the browser decide what width it should have? My guess was that it first allows input to grow to 100% then shrink it (cause the input is in a flex). So maybe the browser calculated the width in the state where the input hasn't shrink yet?

Comment: Yes that is correct @j.xiang

Comment: Cool. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have set `min-width` for the `.input-field`. Remove that and you're all set to go.

```html
<style>
  *{
      margin:0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .parent {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
  }
  .content:nth-child(1) {
      display: flex;
      align-self: flex-end;
  }
  input {
      width: 100%;
  }
  .input-field {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      width: 20%;
      /*min-width: 10rem;
      max-width: 20rem; */
  }
  label {
      margin-right: 0.5rem;
  }
</style>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">
      <div class="input-field">
          <label>hey</label>
          <input type="text">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"><p>hey</p></div>
  <div class="content"><p>you</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But if i remove it the input will be quite small.

Comment: can you mention What  is your desired output?

Comment: To not have the extra space and an input that is at least usable.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width: 20%` from `.input-field`

Comment: Adding this doesn't remove the space on the `.content`...

Answer (score 0):

The input field has a max-width by default, which is approximately 100px (although it varies in different browsers.)
You can restrict its width by overriding the "max-width" property.

Comment: It doesn't work when i add `min-width: 0` on the `input`.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my mistake. The property is "max-width".